# Rails - undefined method `model_name' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

In the edit function, I am fetching the object that will be edited. Unfortunately I have been getting this weird error that I can' understand its cause so far.

```
NoMethodError in Tasks#edit
```

`undefined method`model_name' for `#Hash:0x007fe92d2afeb8` at line#1 in `_form.html.erb`

tasks_controller:

```
def edit
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost/tasks/public/api/tasks/"+params[:id])
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    @task = JSON.parse(response.body)['task']
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`simple_form_for` is expecting you to pass it a model.  Based on that assumption it's trying to call a method that exists on models, but not in your `@task` object, which is the result of a JSON parse.

Comment: so how can I fix this issue?!

Comment: Make @task an instance of your Task model - something like this: `@task = Task.new(JSON.parse(response.body)['task'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `ActiveRecord` classes (or duck typed) with `simple_form`

However `simple_form` can also take a hash instead of a model, something like:

`simple_for_for(:task)`
But then you gotta re-structure you form a bit